# Under what cases will arrow keys not traverse the combobox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a simple `JComboBox`

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"foo", "bar"}));
```

In some cases the arrow keys work for the list traversal in the popup. But in certain cases the arrow keys do not work(no exceptions are raised in these cases).

I have narrowed down to the cases when the arrow keys do not work.

I wanted to know what could lead to the arrow keys not working so that I could limit my focus area. I am sorry but I cannot provide the SSCCE for this problem.

Comment: I understand not being able to provide code, but could you perhaps list the cases where it does or doesn't? Something general to find a pattern from?

Comment: *"I am sorry but I cannot provide the SSCCE for this problem."*  What is stopping or preventing you from doing so?

Comment: @gobernador  I'd +1 that if I had any votes left for today!

Comment: @AndrewThompson for one I would be putting 1/3 my application.

Comment: @gobernador I have got user perspective cases right now. Narrowing down on the code. I posted the question so that I could speed up this process. Will update soon.

Comment: *"Narrowing down on the code."*  Good idea.  I can almost guarantee the problem is in lines of code other than the 2 shown.  And if you remove enough lines and still experience and cannot see the cause of the problem, that is the SSCCE.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson narrowed down to the problem, and got the solution :)

Comment: *"got the solution"*  Cool.  Glad you sorted it.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had removed the ActionMap for the arrow key in my custom autocomplete combobox which extends `JComboBox`

```
getActionMap().getParent().remove("selectNext");
```

I had not reset the action keys when the user entered some value not in the list and moved on. This lead to all the JComboboxes in the application to stop responding to the arrow keys.

I had initially saved the action for the `selectNext` and reset the action at the error incidence mentioned above to get the code working

```
Action selectNextAction = getActionMap().getParent().get("selectNext");
//...
getActionMap().getParent().put("selectNext", selectNextAction);
```